# Python Usando .replace() com list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alguém consegue me dizer se consigo fazer isso funcionar:

```
a = ['<a1>', '<a2>', '<a3>', '', '<a5>']
b = ['<b1>', '<b2>', '<b3>', '', '<b5>']
txt = '<a1> test <a2> test <a3> test <a4> test <a5>'
txt.replace(''.join([i for i in a if i is not '']),''.join([j for j in b if j is not '']))
```

Comment: Qual é o resultado pretendido, o que queres que `txt` seja no final?

Comment: @Miguel quero que `txt` tenha os valores de `a` substituídos pelos de `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta isto, não é com list compreession mas a lógica a adotar será esta:

```
ab = zip(a, b) # relacionar os elementis das listas
for a_val, b_val in ab:
    txt = txt.replace(a_val, b_val)
```

http://ideone.com/TPQpBz

Ou pelos indices:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(a):
    txt = txt.replace(val, b[idx])
```

http://ideone.com/OQCqjm